# Decode image to bitmap ok, but why?

Tags: image, bitmap, png, decode

I would like to know why we need to decode let's say a png to a bitmap in order to show the image. 
Why not just show the png like that (encoded).

I'm asking here a moron type of question on purpose. It's clear to me it's impossible to show an encoded image just like that but I want to know why, and how an image is shown on a screen because it's easy just to do :

```
canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImage)Image).bitmap, x, y, null);
```

I want to understand the full of it. I'm guessing we need to show every pixels one by one, but I want more details.

It's easy to know how to do, it's a bit harder to understand why.

If someone has a course/tuto/article/explanation that explains it... I would appreciate

Thanks in advance

PS : Please don't respond "you need to decode/convert png to bitmap" I know that... And that's not my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of reasons. There is not really a direct relation between 'a value in a file' and 'a pixel on a screen'.

1. You need to know the width and height of the bitmap. You cannot infer this from the image size -- it has to be stored somewhere inside the image file. (Or anywhere else. Point is, *you have to know* its size.)
2. You need to know the bit depth and color model of the bitmap. You cannot meaningfully copy an 8-bit indexed image directly onto a screen that accepts 32-bit BGR ordering with an unused byte, for example.
3. Your example, the [PNG file format](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#4Concepts.EncodingCompression), specifies that all image data is compressed. This is for a sane reason: the PNG format was designed for use on web pages, in a time period where every byte still counted. But even the lowly simple BMP file format uses a very specific form of 'encoding': in its 24-bit format, every line consists of sets of BGR values for each pixel *and* is padded at the end with enough bytes to make its total length evenly divisible by 4.
4. JPEG uses an even more advanced encoding scheme (which is too difficult to explain in a few short words) so it can compress images even more. The advanced encoding scheme allows far more compression than regular methods (which in turn means there is only the tiniest relation between 'values in the file' and 'pixels on the screen').

Comment: I'm going to inform myself a bit more on compression it looks interresting. And I think it's what I need to look for... thank for your time.